# How to set a value and placeholder together for input text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, input, placeholder

I need to put a hint for a text box.I know it can be done via placeholder , but I also need to set value for the same text box (The initial value should be hidden).Is there any way to that rather than some logic?

This occurred while I am developing a mobile app using html5 and jquery-mobile.I am trying to build a custom hour and minute selector.Insted of html is there any option in jquery-mobile?

Thank you

Comment: Its not very clear what you are asking. Have you read the JQM docs on inputs? http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/forms/textinputs/

Comment: @PhillHealey thank you for your responce friend, I need a hint and a value for a test field, If I set value the place holde will disappear, I need both value(hidden) place-holder for an input field, got?

Comment: No, you would need to use the default placeholder, then have default value entered when the input gains focus.

Answer (score 0):

Set the placeholder value via the standard JQM method identified via the JQM docs. Then, have JQuery watch for the user selecting the input field. Then tell JQuery to add a value to the input field.

You could try something like this:

To set an input field with a placeholder:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="input" placeholder="YOUR PLACEHOLDER TEXT">
```

To add the default value:

```
$("#input").focus(function() {
     $(this).InnerHTML("ADD DEFAULT VALUE HERE");
 });
```

[JQuery Placeholder info](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_form_basic.asp)

[JQuery Focus info](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Answer (score 0):

This will help, check and run code snippet here.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById('my-input');
const suffixElement = document.getElementById('my-suffix');


inputElement.addEventListener('input', updateSuffix);

updateSuffix();

function updateSuffix() {
  const width = getTextWidth(inputElement.value, '12px arial');
  suffixElement.style.left = width + 'px';
}



function getTextWidth(text, font) {
    // re-use canvas object for better performance
    var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = font;
    var metrics = context.measureText(text);
    return metrics.width;
}
```

```css
#my-input-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font: 12px arial;
}

#my-input {
  font: inherit;
}

#my-suffix {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 3px;
  color: #555;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-input-container">
  <input type="number" id="my-input" value="15">
  <span id="my-suffix">%</span>
</div>
```