# How to show placeholder name rather than the value name in the input fiels

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an input field and I want to display the placeholder name not the value (*) of that input field.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="sr-only" for="ParkName">Park Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ParkName" value="'*'" placeholder="Park Name" id="park_name"/>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/30npt6wf/

Comment: then just delete from value  *.

Comment: I need that value as default for the php query, if user leaves that field empty

Comment: if user leaves that field empty, then just do something like this in php: `if($_POST['ParkName'] == ""){ $ParkName = "*";} `

Comment: @ Mehemmed Rustemzade. I see that but the problem is that it is a self submitting action form which only filters down (updates) the url parameters so there is no way to write an if or else statement here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var input = $("#park_name").val();
    if(input == ""){
         $("#park_name").val("'*'");
    }    
});

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ParkName"  placeholder="Park Name" id="park_name"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="ParkName"  placeholder="Park Name" id="park_name"/>
```

Just use only placeholder and let the user type the value. `placeholder` is used to show help text ONLY when the textbox is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK to use Javscript then you can try something similar like the links below:
[Show placeholder instead of the default value in html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800328/show-placeholder-instead-of-the-default-value-in-html-form)
[How to set a value and placeholder together for input text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473602/how-to-set-a-value-and-placeholder-together-for-input-text)

Add a listener for the blur/ focus event on the input field, then add your value to the input field.

```
$("#park_name").focus(function() {
 this.value = "'*'";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="ParkName">Park Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ParkName"  placeholder="Park Name" id="park_name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ParkName" value="'*'" id="park_name"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation would go a long way to understanding how you've solved the problem.